# Keeping data after update sqlite version

Tags: android, sqlite

I had 1 table in sqlite database. I changed database version to 2 and add another table.
User data from first table disappeared.
So I am asking you: How can I keep all user data?

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        static int databaseVersion = 2;
        static String databaseName = "DBInformation";

        String table1 = "CREATE TABLE people ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "name TEXT, "+
                "age INTEGER )";

       String table2 = "CREATE TABLE furniture ( " +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                "type TEXT, "+
                "price INTEGER )";




        public Database(Context context) {
            super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             db.execSQL(table1);


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             db.execSQL(table2);
             db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people");

             this.onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Was your first table named people?  Seems to me you deleted the people table, then it got created fresh with onCreate and now has no rows in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I keep all user data?

Don't drop the `people` table. Just create the `furniture` table:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      if (oldVersion<2) {
         db.execSQL(table2);
      }
    }
```

Tomorrow, you might bump the schema version to 3 and add yet another table:

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
      if (oldVersion<2) {
         db.execSQL(table2);
      }

      if (oldVersion<3) {
         db.execSQL(CREATE_RUTABAGA_TABLE_STATEMENT);
      }
    }
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS people");
```

Makes its delete the old people table, remove this line and the people table will retain the data it had before the upgrade.

Comment: I am ashamed that it was just this. Thank you